# My.Settings.Save() doesn't seem to be saving my form's location

Tags: vb.net, save

I am trying to save my form's location so that when the user comes back, its location will be in the same place.

However, no matter what, my setting does not appear to save, and I've no idea why. I use the `My.Settings.Save()` method right after I set the setting and then close the form, reopen it, and see it appear in a different location than the one I chose.

I tried saving the settings first with this:

```
Private Sub MenuForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    My.Settings.MenuPosition = Me.Location
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

And because that didn't work I tried this:

```
 Private Sub MenuForm_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.LocationChanged
    My.Settings.MenuPosition = Me.Location
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

And I've tried setting it again in different events with that same code, but had the same result.

Here is my code for loading the form:

```
Private Sub Menu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Location = New Point(My.Settings.MenuPosition)
    Me.BackColor = My.Settings.MenuColor
    Me.Label1.ForeColor = My.Settings.MenuTextColor
    If My.Settings.FirstOpen = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Hello! Please drag your menu into its desired position.", "WikiFinder")
        My.Settings.FirstOpen = False
        'Remember to set to false when done...
    ElseIf My.Settings.MusicMenu = True Then
        MusicMenu.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, to confirm the setting isn't saving, and forgive me if this is bad practice for debugging, I had a message box appear displaying the setting when I saved it, and another one when I loaded the setting. Both had different texts.

Also I should add, all of my settings' scopes are set to `User`.

Can anybody explain what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you set the scope of the property to `User`? `Application` scopes properties can't be saved at runtime

Comment: Yes, I saw stuff about that on the Internet while researching this. I double-checked, and all my settings' scopes are User. I'll include that in the question.

Comment: By default settings are scoped to User and also by default under project properties application tab Save My.Settings on ShutDown is set to true which means there is no need for My.Settings.Save. Did you set Form.Location to Manual and try this?

Comment: I also tried turning off saving settings on shutdown, didn't help. I'll try setting Form.Location to manual though.

Comment: What data type did u define location in settings?

Comment: @KarenPayne, it's the `StartPosition` property of the form that needs to be set to `Manual`, in order that setting the `Location` before displaying has any effect.

Comment: My.Settings.Save() no longer works in DotNet 4.5 and up. Scoping to User won't help you. See solution below or create your own settings file.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is still up, here's a kind of workaround. I'm not sure if this is a possibility for you though.

One solution would be writing the Values in a file, which is then read at the restart of the program. Here's how to do it:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Path, Text, Append [as Boolean])
```

So, in your case, you could do this:

```
Private Sub SaveLocation() Handles Me.LocationChanged
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Path, Me.Location.X & ";" & Me.Location.Y, False)
End Sub
```

This would write the location of the window in the specified file, seperated by an `;`. Now you have to read this file on startup of the program:

```
Dim LastX As Integer
Dim LastY As Integer

Private Startup() Handles Me.Load
    Try
        Dim Data As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path) 'Read Data from File
        LastX = Data.Split(";")(0) 'Set LastX Variable by splitting the Data-String
        LastY = Data.Split(";")(1) 'Set LastY Variable by splitting the Data-String

        Me.Location = New Point(LastX, LastY) 'Set the location of the window
    Catch NoAccess As UnauthorizedAccessException
        'Executed when the user has no access to the Settings File
    Catch Ex As Exception
        'First Open Procedure
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now, let me explain a bit. `My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText()` reads all the Text from the specified file. In our case, the Settings File. So we store the Text from the file in a variable called `Data`. Now, because we seperated the coordinates with an `;`, we can read the file value by value. `.Split()` actually returns an array of strings, for example:
Our String is `10;20;30`. If we use `.Split(";")` our string gets split at every `;`. As a result, we get an array with following values:`(10, 20, 30)`. Now we can read the different values by specifying the index we want to read. In our example string, value 0 would be 10, value 1 would be 20 and value 2 would be 30.

I hope I didn't confuse you, this was my first answer here on StackOverflow.

Happy Coding, Mika